# how do i insert a variable? from a form into a file_get_contents link

Tags: php, string, hyperlink, file-get-contents

how do i insert a variable from a form into a file_get_contents("link+formdata")

the variable being submitted via a form and contains  full stops,Numbers,letter

Example: danny.29 would replace HERE in the link below:

file_get_contents("http://userapi.website.com/HERE");

As you can see i'm very new to this, any help would be very much appreciated :)

index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
ID: <input type="text" name="add">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

add.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php $x=$_POST['add'];?>

<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://userapi.website.com/"echo $x;");
?>

<?php echo $_POST["file_get_contents"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://userapi.website.com/" . $x); ?>
```

Dot is for [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: You can do concatenation within the string with curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $_POST["file_get_contents"]; ?>
```

doesn't make sense. The POST array will only contain the `add` key on the first load.

```
echo file_get_contents("http://userapi.website.com/". $x);
```

will get correctly the content of the address page but to memorize it into a variable you just have to do:

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://userapi.website.com/". $x);
```

Also this script is no totally secure. You should always validate user input (your POST variable in this case). I'd suggest you to use a REGEX or a list of acceptable values for that variable.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, one problem is there a syntax/code error there? http://i.imgur.com/gtskZmC.png seems like its missing something as wont run online ?