# Insert Variable into file_get_contents from HTML form

Tags: php, html

I've used the answer given here ([how do i insert a variable? from a form into a file_get_contents link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310614/how-do-i-insert-a-variable-from-a-form-into-a-file-get-contents-link)) however, It is still not working for me.

But this is not working, I do not know why?

Comment: `$code = $_POST['search'];` need to be before the `file_get_contents()` don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place/assign your POST array and variable first, not after:
*(Kind of like putting the horse after the wagon, as it were)*.

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['search'];
$json = file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/user=". $code);
$obj = json_decode($json);
?>
```

Because as it stands, you'd be getting an "Undefined index/variable..." notice, had you been checking for errors.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @Jay You're welcome Jay. Plus, I didn't see AbraCadaver's comment; I was preparing my answer at the same time it was written. *Just for the record* ;-)